# Check if any field of a record has change dyncamically for a bulk trigger

Tags: apex, trigger, before-trigger, describesobject, describefieldresult

I am trying to run validation in before update trigger which checks if a field value has changed in a particular status for the record. If it has changed then it adds a validation error.

I wanted to build it dynamically in Apex where I do not have to add field details in trigger everytime a new field is added to the record.

I am using the following piece of code:

```
  public static void validationOnBookingUpdateWhenCaseIsDelayed(Map<Id, Booking__c> bookingOldMap, List<Booking__c> bookingNewList){
    Map<String,Schema.SObjectField> mfields = Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get('Booking__c').getDescribe().fields.getMap();
    for(Booking__c bookingNewRecord : bookingNewList){
        for(Schema.SObjectField sField : mfields.values()){
            if(String.valueOf(sField) != 'Booking_Status__c'){
                if((bookingNewRecord.get('Booking_Status__c') == 'Delayed' || bookingNewRecord.get('Booking_Status__c') == 'Discontinued') &&
                   bookingNewRecord.get(sField) != bookingOldMap.get(bookingNewRecord.Id).get(sField)){
                       bookingNewRecord.addError('Cannot change');
                   }                    
            }   
            
        }
    }
}
```

My issue here is that, I am not getting a way to do it without the nested for loop. Any advice would be really helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there's a way to compare all fields at once, but if you want to include which fields are changed, a nested loop is your only option. If you only want to detect that any field has changed, you can do that by comparing the two records directly:

```
for(Booking__c bookingNewRecord : bookingNewList){
    if(bookingNewRecord.Booking_Status__c != 'Delayed' && bookingNewRecord.Booking_Status__c != 'Discontinued') {
        continue;
    }
    // Clear out audit fields, etc
    Booking__c newValues = bookingNewRecord.clone(false, false, false, false);
    Booking__c oldValues = bookingOldMap.get(bookingNewRecord.Id).clone(false, false, false, false);
    // Set both clones to null so it will work in the next step
    newValues.Booking_Status__c = oldValues.Booking_Status__c = null;
    // Comparing two sobjects compares all their contents
    if(oldValues != newValues) {
        bookingNewRecord.addError('Cannot change');
    }
}
```

This makes it trivial to figure out if you need the error. However, if you want to tell the user *which* fields have changed, you'd still need an inner for loop.

Comment: Thank you so much. I don't need to have the list of fields that have been edited. I just need to show a message that no values can be changed. This is a great piece of logic. Thank you for explaining it so well. @sfdcfox